# Show the User Outlook Personnel calendar inside SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, powerapp

Inside our communication site home page >> we want to show the login user Outlook personnel calendar. So is this possible? using built-in web parts or using Power Apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the [Personal Calendar web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/wp-personal-calendar.md) from the SharePoint starter kit.

Comment: not sure how this will work? will it automatically get the events for the login user? or we need to configure this for each user? i tried to test this but i got this error `Failed to load component "6d28e73b-ed80-494e-8238-c0106c26b36a" (PersonalCalendarWebPart). Original error: Manifest not found for component id "849381c3-2209-441c-a559-2dc6a5c0cb63" and version "1.0.0".`

Comment: Have you ensured it has appropriate access to the Microsoft Graph? https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/wp-personal-calendar.md#installing-the-web-part

Comment: As you can see from this GIF, it just shows the current user's personal calendar when they get to the page: https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/raw/master/assets/images/components/part-personal-calendar.gif

Comment: yes it do .. not sure why it is not working at my end. also will it automatically get the events for the login user? or we need to configure this for each user?

Comment: It will get the events for the current user, I have already commented this. You'll need to debug why that the web part isn't working in your environment.